# How to reload mod_jk

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mod-jk

I work under Ubuntu.
Each time I restart apache2, it tells me that jk_module is already loaded, so it skips it.
Problem : I think I misconfigured something, so I changed it, but since it is not reloaded, change are not taken.
So, How can I reload mod_jk?

Comment: Since this is a question about server software, and not really about programming, it is probably better asked at http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know there were different parts! I will do this, thanks for the tipp

Comment: Yup, there's a [whole host of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for various topics.

Comment: Well... this is impressive!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Open the Apache configuration file
- Search for the `jk_module` string:

  ```
  # Load mod_jk module
  LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so
  ```
- Remove all instances except the first
- Restart Apache

**References**

- [Apache HTTP Server HowTo: Simple Configuration Example](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html#Simple%20configuration%20example)